# Latex: \newcommand interpret # symbol problem

Tags: latex

I defined a new command

```
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\href{https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/package.json#1}{#1}}
```

When I use it as follows:

```
\test{#L4}
```

the url will be interpreted as:

```
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/package.json##L4
```

There is an extra `#` in the url, which is unexpected. What I really want is:

```
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/package.json#L4
```

which means line 4 of the package.json code

The easiest but no so elegant way to solve the problem is as follows.

```
\test{\#L4}
```

but what if other special characters like `_` appear in the part of url I copy? It's boring to correct these meaningless grammar mistakes.

Is there any more elegant way to solve the problem? What I want is to copy plain text, which is part of url to the latex code and no extra efforts like adding `\` escape character before `#` and other special characters are needed.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35310/problem-with-use-of-in-custom-href-command

Comment: The link above solved my problems. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to copy plain text, which is part of url to the latex code and no extra efforts like adding \ escape character before # and other special characters are needed.

I am afraid it will require extra effort because `#` is used as a parameter for macros in LaTeX. You can play with redefining categories and when `#` is consumed, restore its original meaning.

I have another solution based on `expl3` where I save the main address and create links with additional parts. See a small demo below

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}       % To fit long links without breaks

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N  \l__xaddr_main_str
\str_new:N  \l__xaddr_show_str
\cs_new:Npn \combine_addr:n #1 {
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \str_concat:NNN \l__xaddr_show_str \l__xaddr_main_str \l_tmpa_str
}
\NewDocumentCommand\xsetmainaddr{v}{
    \str_set:Nn \l__xaddr_main_str {#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand\xdisplay{v}{%
    \str_if_empty:NF \l__xaddr_main_str {
        \combine_addr:n {#1}
        \str_use:N \l__xaddr_show_str
    }}
\NewDocumentCommand\xhref{vv}{%
    \str_if_empty:NF \l__xaddr_main_str {
        \combine_addr:n {#1}
        \href{\l__xaddr_show_str}{#2}
    }}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength\parindent{0pt}               % To fit long links without breaks


\begin{document}
\xhref{#L4}{GitHub}                     % Nothing to display. The main address is not defined.

\xsetmainaddr{https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/package.json}
\par\xdisplay{#L4}                      % Display the full address including #L4
\par\xdisplay{#something_else%20here}   % all characters accepted
\par\xhref{#L4}{GitHub}                 % Generates link: <address>#L4

\bigskip

\xsetmainaddr{http://www.google.com}   % New address
\par\xhref{}{Google}                    % Generates link
\end{document}
```